# GroupBOx Content WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I have GroupBox name groupBox1 and it contains StackPanel. In the StackPanel I have serevral ChechBoxes. In my xaml.cs I want to get those CheckBoxes but when i write the next code line I get a zero :

```
int n = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(groupBox1);
```

If I write the next code line I get exeption :

> "Specified index is out of range or
>   child at index is null. Do not call
>   this method if VisualChildrenCount
>   returns zero, indicating that the
>   Visual has no children. Parameter
>   name: index Actual value was 0."

```
Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(groupBox1, 0);
```

It means that my groupBox1 doesn't have any children.... but what about the StackPanel?

I have this function which should itarete over the VisualTree , it looks like this :

```
private void VisualChildren (Visual myVisual)
{          
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
    {
        Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);

        //Some operations

        VisualChildren(childVisual);
    }
}
```

It does not take the `StackPanel` in the `groupBox1`......

Can anyone please tell me how can i get to those `CheckBoxes`?
Thank you.

---

This is my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MyClass"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test" Height="300" Width="300" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Name="win1">
     <Grid Name="grid1">
        <GroupBox Header="GroupBox" Margin="0,0,95,124" Name="groupBox1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="105">
                <CheckBox Height="Auto" Name="checkBox4" Width="Auto" Margin="2">CheckBox</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Height="Auto" Name="checkBox2" Width="Auto" Margin="2">CheckBox</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Height="Auto" Name="checkBox3" Width="Auto" Margin="2">CheckBox</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Height="Auto" Name="checkBox5" Width="Auto" Margin="2">CheckBox</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Height="Auto" Name="checkBox1" Width="Auto" Margin="2">CheckBox</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Height="Auto" Name="checkBox6" Width="Auto" Margin="2">CheckBox</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Height="Auto" Name="checkBox7" Width="Auto" Margin="2">CheckBox</CheckBox>
           </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="wrap2" Margin="8"    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Button Margin="5" Height="23"   Name="button1"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75">Button</Button>
            <Button Margin="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75">Button</Button>
            <Button Margin="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">Button</Button>
            <Button Margin="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Name="button4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">Button</Button>
            <Button Margin="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Name="button5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">Button</Button>
            <Button Margin="5" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Name="button6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">Button</Button>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and this is the code :

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            VisualChildren(grid1);
        }
    }

    private void VisualChildren(Visual myVisual)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
        {
            Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(childVisual.ToString());
            VisualChildren(childVisual);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the problem is that you are trying to get visual children of an element before it gets loaded. At that moment the visual tree hasn't been composed yet. Try subscribing to the `Loaded` event of your group box and get the visual children in the event handler:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VisualChildren(grid1);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks , I will try that , but how the Grid and the other StackPanels that i have in my Window are working in this method and i can use their children?

Comment: If you posted your XAML and where you are trying to get visual children in both cases it might help to diagnose the problem.